# ERROR: npm v9.6.7 is known not to run on Node.js v18.17.1

Tags: node.js, npm-install, nvm, nvm-windows

I am using nvm to manage my Node.js versions. Recently, I installed Node.js version 18.17.1 using nvm, but when I try to use npm, I get the following error message:

`ERROR: npm v9.6.7 is known not to run on Node.js v18.17.1.`

I previously used Node.js version 16.13.0. So I tried switching to this version and re-install Node.js version 18.17.1. But it didn't work.
Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error message, and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with Node.js v18.17.0.  I solved it by removing environment variables from previous Node.js installs.  Specifically, I removed the npm and node.js variables from System Parameters, path.